# How to "scale" all the elements in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am developing an app and something is driving me crazy. On the library page (https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#button) all the components are rendered in a nice size.

[image]
[image]
But in my application, without setting anything, everything is small. Something like half the size: 
 [image]
[image]

Im now, 2 full days trying to render the things right, changing the fontSize or overriding properties with the MUI, but it has a lot of colateral effects, like padding or outlines being out of scale.

Is there a way to say to MUI : "Ok. I want everything double the size. The paddings, font sizes, effects, etc..."

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Material-UI uses rem units for the font size, and rem units are relative to the font-size of the root element of your webpage.

So, if you can change the font-size of the root element of your webpage, all the Material UI components will follow, "scaling up" or "scaling down", depending on the change in value.

The default font-size of the browser html element is 16px. So, if you change it from 16px to 24px for example, all Material UI components will scale up in 50% as well, like so (in your root css):

```
html {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Or you can change the font-size of of Material-UI providing a fontSize property (the default value is 14px), like so:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontSize: 12,
  },
});
```

More information from the documentation of Material UI:

> Material-UI uses rem units for the font size. The browser 
> element default font size is 16px, but browsers have an option to
> change this value, so rem units allow us to accommodate the user's
> settings, resulting in a better accessibility support. Users change
> font size settings for all kinds of reasons, from poor eyesight to
> choosing optimum settings for devices that can be vastly different in
> size and viewing distance.
>
> To change the font-size of Material-UI you can provide a fontSize
> property. The default value is 14px.

Font source: https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#font-size

Comment: This addresses the font size, but not the other elements. The question mentioned "like padding or outlines being out of scale" - I think the goal is to scale the non-text elements accordingly (e.g. double text size, then double all other padding/margins to keep the same ratio), similar to if you zoomed a screen